# Glassfish + SqlServer + Liferay Bug

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling, liferay

I keep getting errors related to connection pool when I try to deploy liferay.
My connection pool seems to be setup correctly. What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are configuring Glassfish with SqlServer using the javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource the DataSource Classname should be com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource and not what Glassfish provides: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ConnectionPoolSQLServerDataSource

Thanks!